# How to select list in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, list, pandas, select, types

I have a dataframe which contains list item in a single cell.

For example, data frame 'home'

```
a       b                  c
'book'  ['living room']   ['cat','foo']
'shoes' ['door']          ['man','woman']
'cook'  []                ['knife']
```

The question is how do I select the 'cook' based on b == [] (empty list).

like

```
home.loc[home.b==[]]
```

BTW, I created the list using lambda x : [] function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
home.loc[home['b'].str.len()==0]
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [313]: d
Out[313]:
       a              b             c
0   book  [living room]    [cat, foo]
1  shoes         [door]  [man, woman]
2   cook             []       [knife]

In [314]: lst = ['cat','foo']

In [315]: d.loc[d['c'].astype(str) == str(lst)]
Out[315]:
      a              b           c
0  book  [living room]  [cat, foo]
```

Comment: Thank you, but I mean can I select a specific row rather than check by length. It's a little bit dodgy.

Comment: @Zhonghao.KevinXie, i've added a small demo - is that what you want?

Comment: It works. Please see my updating, is there a efficient way to select one if there are two items in a list. Since my real data has multiple items in a list.

Comment: @Zhonghao.KevinXie Please don't hijack your question midway. If your question was answered, open a new one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, @MaxU method is optimal, I think.

However, you can try this:

```
home.loc[home.b.apply(lambda x: x == [])]
```

Output:

```
      a   b        c
2  cook  []  [knife]
```

Comment: Thank you. It's helpful, but as @MaxU answered first, I ticked him.